# Page does not stop loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am finding that in my application when I redirect to a new controller method that the View for that controller method does not stop loading.

Some of the CSS does not complete rendering and the page is unresponsive.

As a test I decided to make the view as simple as possible to see if that loads. To my surprise it does not.
So from the code below I would be surprised if you can see what the problem is. However my question is how do I find out what is wrong? I am using ie9 and VS 2012 and I do NOT have access to ANTS.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FullSearch(BulkDeleteSearchViewModel bulkDeleteSearchViewModel)
    {
        SessionObjectsSCD.CompanyType = 
            CacheObjects.CompanyTypes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TypeId == bulkDeleteSearchViewModel.TypeId);
        var type = (CompanyTypeEnum)SessionObjectsSCD.CompanyType.TypeId;
        var strategy = BulkDeleteSearchFactory.Get(type, bulkDeleteSearchViewModel);
        var bulkDeleteSearchService = new BulkDeleteSearchService(strategy);
        SessionObjectsSCD.SearchCompanies = bulkDeleteSearchService.SearchCompany();
        return this.RedirectToAction(type == CompanyTypeEnum.Subcontractor ? 
            "FullListSubcontractor" : "FullList1");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "SCDTopLevelUser, SCDAdmin, SCDDeveloper")]
    public ActionResult FullList1(int page = 1)
    {
        return this.View();
    }
```

The FullList1 view looks like;

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FullList1";
}

<h2>FullList1</h2>
```

The layout view looks like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding a manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SCD</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")" />

        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleDataTablesCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleMenuCss)
        @*@Styles.Render(Constants.BundleBaseCss)*@
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleDemosCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleMobileCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundlePagedListCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleBootstrapCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleSiteCss)
        @Styles.Render(Constants.BundleSunnyThemeCss)
        @Scripts.Render(Constants.BundleModernizr) 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <input type="hidden" id="Environment" value="@AppSettings.EnvironmentSetting.ToUpper()"/>

            <header id="mainHeader">
                <div id="title">
                    <div style="float:left;">@Content.Image("MulalleyLogoSmall.jpg", "float:left;padding:10px 10px 0 10px", Url)</div>
                    <div class="head" style="float:left;padding-top:15px;">SubContractor Database (SCD)</div>
                </div>

                <div id="logindisplay">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div> 

                <nav>
                    @Html.Partial("_MenuItems")
                </nav>
            </header>

            <section class="main-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
            <footer>
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -Copyright Mulalley and Company Limited
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <ul id="social">
                            <li><a href="http://liveweb.sherrygreengrp.com/SHP/" ><b>SHP</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://liveweb.sherrygreengrp.com/STAS/"><b>STAS</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        @Scripts.Render(Constants.BundleScd)
        @Scripts.Render(Constants.BundleDataTables)
        @Scripts.Render(Constants.BundleSubcontractorDetail)
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your Layout? Also what happens if you get rid of all the noise from your controller action? Since you have simplified the view you probably don't need that as well in order to have a repro scenario.

Comment: From Fiddler I got this message: HTTP Error 407 Proxy authentication required. "This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required."

Comment: I tried accessing the view directly from the menu, and it rendered fine. So the problem is to do with the Redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by putting too much data in internal memory. I am surprised that the bug could not be identified in a more obvious way, but lesson learnt.